# How can I have a validation formula for a Decimal field that is only tested if the field is non-blank

Tags: orbeon

In Form Builder, I have a control of Data Type: Decimal. Required is set to No. I want to have a validation error if a value entered is not positive. But I don't want a validation error if the field is blank. I have tried a lot of formulas such as these:

```
xxf:is-blank(xs:string($control-2)) or $control-2 > 0
string-length(xs:string($control-2)) = 0 or $control-2 > 0

xxf:is-blank($control-2) or $control-2 > 0
string-length($control-2) = 0 or $control-2 > 0
```

If the field is non-blank I can convert it to string with xs:string() without any issue but if it's blank then this conversion fails. Is there any formula to test for a blank Decimal value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in Form Builder you make the field non-required and Decimal, in the XForms, you'll have a `type="xf:decimal"`. Then, as for the constraint, just writing `xxf:is-blank() or . > 0` seems to work for me. I see that this is pretty much equivalent to your 3rd expression, so I might be missing something. If that is the case, feel free to let me know in the comments.

And for reference, this is what I had in the *Validations and Alerts* tab:

[image: Validations and Alerts]

Comment: Apparently the behaviour of xxf:is-blank() is different from that of xxf:is-blank(.) and xxf:is-blank($control-2). I don't understand why that would be the case. But this does seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, I think we should have been able to solve this by selecting "Positive" from the drop-down instead of writing a formula. Unfortunately this will generate an error message when the field is blank even when Required is set to No. I don't think it should work that way.

Comment: In XML Schema, there is a `xs:positiveInteger`, but no `xs:positiveDecimal`, but I agree, adding this in the dropdown as a possibility would be a good addition. We'll discuss about this internally, and see if it makes sense to have an RFE for this.

Comment: We had a quick discussion about this here, and I think the bottom line is that implementing [RFE 3156](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3156) would solve this issue you're having. I added a +1 from you on that issue. And in the meantime, you indeed need to use `xxf:is-blank() or …` as part of your condition.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for the note.